# What would cause a C++ object's type information to change after it is returned from a function?

Tags: c++

## Introduction

I have C++17 code of the following form:

```
Base& makeDerived(int val) {
  std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = secondLayer(val);
  std::cout << typeid(derived).name() << std::endl;
  return *derived;
}

int main(void) {
    Base& derived = makeDerived(7);
    std::cout << typeid(derived).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I can get this code to either print:

```
Derived
Derived
```

or

```
Derived
Base
```

with different implementations of Derived and Base, but I don't understand why this would happen.

### Supplemental Notes

The actual code I am basing this question on prints: `Derived, Base` but it would be much too long to paste, and I wouldn't be authorized to do so. I can't figure out how to distill it down to a characteristic example, all efforts seem to print `Derived, Derived`, and the fact that I can't distill it down is basically what my problem is because I don't understand why it would be different.

In all implementations I care about, `Derived` is a descendant of `Base`.

### Question

*What would cause a descendant of a base class to change its type information to the base class itself after exiting a function?*

Comment: undefined behavior can explain anything (and nothing)

Comment: "I can get this code to either print ... or ... with different implementations of Derived and Base." Please provide all relevant implementations so your code becomes a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: You'd need to show what implementations create what output. You're asking people to divine an answer otherwise.

Comment: Ask yourself: After `return *derived;`,  what happens to `derived` in the function?

Comment: The glaring issue is that the function returns a dangling reference. Whether the implementation of `Base` and `Derived` is correct is a secondary question.

Comment: Works on my machine.  I probably didn't put in the bug in my code that is in the code snippet provided which does not reproduce the bug.  A [mcve] would be helpful, because I had to guess at `secondLayer` which could be the cause of your code's problem.

Comment: *What would cause a descendant of a base class to change its type information to the base class itself after exiting a function?*  **Undefined behavior** can do that, such as by accessing an object after it has been destructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear how you can get output of `Derived Derived` or `Derived Base`, because `derived` is a `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`. Anyhow, here is a minimal example with the same issue as your code (most likely):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base { virtual ~Base() = default; };
struct Derived : Base {};

std::shared_ptr<Derived> secondLayer(int) { return std::make_shared<Derived>(); }

Base& makeDerived(int val) {
  std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = secondLayer(val);
  std::cout << typeid(derived).name() << std::endl;
  return *derived;
}

int main(void) {
    Base& derived = makeDerived(7);
    std::cout << typeid(derived).name() << std::endl;
}
```

[possible output](https://godbolt.org/z/ods5sqMcd):

```
St10shared_ptrI7DerivedE
4Base
```

I was planning to put a disclaimer here on how you should pay attention to warnings and use the compilers instrumentation capabilities. However, gcc silently swallows this code with `-Wall -Werror` and neither `-fsanitize-address` nor `-fsanitize-undefined` do help. I would consider this as a bug.

However, `return *derived` is returning a reference to an object that gets destroyed once the function returns. Using that reference in `main` causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about this answer on the following link:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

The implementation of Base and Derived class can be made using different approaches, and what can do a difference in the use of typeid is the polymorohic or non polymorphic inheritance.

A class derived from a base class that owns virtual methos is considered a polymorphic inheritance.
In case of a polymorphic inheritance typeid is able to recognize the real type of the instance (even in your case, where you are casting it in a reference to Base class).

A class derived from a base class that doesn't own any virtual mehotd is considered a non polymorphic inheritance and typeid can't recognize the real type of the instance you are using, and in your case will return a std::type_info that refer to the type Base&.

Answer (score 1):

You create a shared ptr.  Then you return a reference and destroy the last reference.

Inspecting the value through the reference is going to be undefined behaviour.

So you'll get any behaviour at all.  Sometimes what you want, sometimes not.